# How to run application in background in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a dotnet application and I want to publish it in the container. I have one requirement, when the application is started I have to push some data in my application.
To do that I created a shell script and put it in the entry point command. Now I am running my application using a shell script.

The problem is when the application is started the script is not running the commands below it.

This is my shell script:

```
cd /app/WebAPI
dotnet WebAPI.dll
cd /app/data
for f in `ls *.txt`; do
  // some other command
done
```

I want to run this for loop after the application is started.

Comment: Put `&` after the command to put it in the background.

Comment: it does not keep running the dotnet application and the below commands are running when the application is stopped. I want to keep running my dotnet application.

Comment: It has no sense to loop over the output of `ls *.txt`, just put `for f in *.txt;`. In some cases, the output of `ls` is including some extra chars to make its output readable by humans, but that will mess your code.

Comment: You have to put the `&` after the `dotnet` command, like this: `dotnet WebAPI.dll &`

Comment: @PierreFrançois ```&``` is working but it stops executing my app and then running the other commands.

Comment: What do you mean with "is working but it stops"? Why does `dotnet` stop, in your opinion?

Comment: Then there is probably something wrong with your dotnet script / call. Try this simple script : `{sleep 5 && echo "end sleep"} &; echo "end script"`. You'll see that `end sleep` is displayed even after the script has finished executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments above:

```
cd /app/WebAPI
dotnet WebAPI.dll &
cd /app/data
for f in *.txt; do
  # some other command
done
```